# MySQL Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' but a bit more weird

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I am having a common problem. I read all over google, but my problem is a bit more weird.

I have a table I use these primary keys:

```
ALTER TABLE `companies`
   ADD PRIMARY KEY(
     `name_employee`,
     `email`);
```

So the primary key is a compination of `name_employee` AND `email`.

The problem with examples (I give only the primary key's insertions as others are not primary and working as expected):

First insertion OK:

```
name_employee = 'Pavlos Pavlos'
email = 'company_Name@gmail.com'
```

Second insertion OK:

```
name_employee = 'John John'
email = 'company_Name@gmail.com'
```

Third insertion BAD:

```
name_employee = 'Nick Nick'
email = 'company_Name@gmail.com'
```

Error that pops up:

> Error: INSERT INTO companies (name, account_number, dateExp,
>   credit_limit, amount_debt, balance, name_employee, id_employee,
>   email, password) SELECT name, account_number, dateExp, credit_limit,
>   amount_debt, balance, 'Nick Nick', '250', 'company_Name@gmail.com',
>   'pass' FROM companies WHERE email='company_Name@gmail.com' 
>   **Duplicate entry 'Nick Nick-company_Name@gmail.com' for key 'PRIMARY'**

But there isn't another row with `name_employee = Nick Nick` and `email = company_Name@gmail.com`.

**What is really weird is that it lets me do a second insertion with the same `email` but a different `name_employee`, but it doesn't let me do the same for a third and so on insertion.**

Any help please?

**EDIT:
This is an assignment and I cannot add more keys/primary keys etc.
Also I need under the same company a lot of employees that's and we can assume that name_employee is different for each one that's why I used these primary keys.**

Comment: Your insert-select is attempting to insert two rows; run the select by itself to see.

Comment: You probably don't want that to be the primary key, it makes records really obnoxious to retrieve and a ton of hassle to link to from other tables. Have a simple `INT` primary and make a secondary `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: @tadman Please check first post at the end, I made an edit.

Comment: @Uueerdo so what I shall do to insert 1 more row but only with 2 different values (name_employee, id_employee) ?

Comment: You could just add `LIMIT 1`; however, I would argue against the method you are using in general. You have no guarantee that all records with `email='company_Name@gmail.com'` are identical in every other regard other than `name_employee`. If/when that happens, which values you get will be chosen effectively at random. _(If you want to store the "default" values as a row, I would recommend giving that row a unique `name_employee, email`, and WHERE-ing on both fields' values.)_

Comment: @Uueerdo the other values/records are always identical except name_employee and id_employee which are the ones that I change everytime I make an insertion. The others are identical by default on my project. So LIMIT 1 works for me right?

Comment: So none of `name`, `account_number`, `dateExp`, `credit_limit`, `amount_debt`, `balance`, and `password` **never** change until `email` has been changed from `'company_Name@gmail.com'`? _And to echo others, why are you so averse to a straight forward `INSERT VALUES` query?_

Comment: I am not averse. I am just saying that LIMIT works in my case. Also, `amount_debt` and `balance` change, but change for all rows that have the same `email`. So in the end, all rows have the same values except the two stated before about the employees. To be clear again, I am not averse or anything, just saying that LIMIT works in my case also.

Comment: This gives me the creeps ;-) A table named `companies` should contain companies. But yours contains employees it seems. Then the primary key is the employee's name (which can change on marriage) and email (which is also subject to change). A primary key should never change. Then you expect many columns to be fix for an email address. Why then is there not a table having *one* row per email holding these values? You should definitly think over your database design in my opinion.

Comment: As I seed before, these are from a project/assignment I have. And by default email or names cannot be changed. Also they want this implementation of database as it is stated like this in the assignment.

Comment: Okay, so it's not you but someone else. You should tell them that their database is horrible and they should change it. (Maybe this is just what they wanted you to do when they gave you this strange assignment :-)

Comment: Nah, the overall assignment and what they want are a bit tricky and "weird". I am not even sure they that know for sure what they want. :P 

Anyway, if you want, you can post the 2 answers, 1 with LIMIT other with values so I can give you an accepted answer. :)

Comment: Everything about this database is truly, apocalyptically wrong. It violates so many rules of normalization I can only suppose they're subjecting you to this to show you how bad things can get. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query

```
SELECT 
  name, account_number, dateExp, credit_limit, amount_debt, balance, 
  'Nick Nick', '250', 'company_Name@gmail.com', 'pass' 
FROM companies 
WHERE email='company_Name@gmail.com'
```

selects rows from table `companies` where `email` equals `'company_Name@gmail.com'`. This is true for two rows (`'Pavlos Pavlos'` and `'John John'`). So you are trying to insert `'Nick Nick'` twice. Hence the error.

.

Comment: I get it, is there a way to select only one row for each occurance?

Comment: Why do you select from the table anyway? Why not use a values clause instead? What is it you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Seems like I need to change it if there is not other way.

Comment: You could get one row with a limit clause for instance, but it looks queer to me to pick one record arbitrarily to build a new record.

Comment: You shouldn't be selecting from the table to insert new values like this. Like Thorsten says, Insert with Values will work.